# Use SharePoint as Ftp from PHP

Tags: file-upload, php, file-download

I am definitely new with SharePoint.I own a PHP site where the users could manually upload a zipped file to sharepoint, and than users copied back the file's URL to a form page's field and save into DB. After this a Cron process uploaded the files from SharePoint to web site (FTP) server with a curl function when the site is not usable by a lot users.

I would like now that the users automatically could do the process. They click on a form's button than navigate to the SharePoint upload their files. The file's storage address than would be returned automatically when PHP form is submitted,so it could saved into the site DB.

I also need to transfer later the files to the server from the SharePoint. Would be great if this could be done automatically(by the saved URL address in the DB) by an API. Would be do this with my private Microsoft account or I can ask an account for my server from MS?

At the SharePoint the files must be storage like YouTube unlisted, if the address know by other must be accessable.-

How should I set this in SharePoint? How do I setup the (whole)environment in SharePoint?How can I restrict that only users with specific domain in their email are able to access the content? How can I restrict that the user could upload only zipped files?

I hope you understand my very limited knowledge in this subject, thank you very much for help in advance

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online?

Comment: @CallumCrowley I use the o365, I am not sure if SharePoint online, where to check it?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to authentication, you could use an Azure AD app registration in order to authenticate with SharePoint or the Microsoft Graph APIs. You can then use [app-only permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) to grant access to SharePoint.

SharePoint Online doesn't work like a public facing website, so to access the files they will generally need to authenticate first. It's possible to create temporary URLs to access files though.

*How can I restrict that only users with specific domain in their email are able to access the content?*

[Restrict sharing of SharePoint and OneDrive content by domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/restricted-domains-sharing)

*How can I restrict that the user could upload only zipped files?*

I'm not aware of any way to do this in SharePoint Online out-of-the-box but users could upload zip files from a form on your website and then your website could upload the zip file to SharePoint on their behalf. The file type check could be completed by your website.

Comment: Thank you very much your help,time and effort. The files are huge at least 4-500MB. That's why I can not upload to my FTP directly, otherwise it would crash the site when 2-300 people began simultantly upload their files

Comment: I'm not sure how you would limit users to only uploading zip files without a custom interface e.g. your website/a Power App or a bespoke application of some sort